# Strange vertical alignment error in math mode text in the "Related Questions" list

Tags: bug, specific-question, design

This concerns the "Related Questions" list I can see tied to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831485/determine-whether-or-not-the-poset-mathbbn-propto-has-a-least-element/3961870#3961870). A picture of the relevant link is below:

[image]

Notice how, in the $(4,4)$ ordered pair, the left $4$ is one pixel below the right $4$.

I originally thought this might be -- somehow -- tied to a custom command I used on the page to help make my answer, which was simply having `\p` render `\propto`. However, the error persisted, in a sense. Before removing my command, I instead had this issue, where every ordered pair *except* $(4,4)$ had the issue; removing the command made it affect *only* $(4,4)$ on my viewing:

[image]

Perhaps adding some lines will make the misalignment particularly clear:

[image]

Some other notes:

- This error does not seem to exist for me on Firefox. (The above pictures are tied to the newest version of Google Chrome; for what it's worth, I'm using Windows 10.)

[image]

- This error **does** apear on Microsoft Edge:

[image]

- This error does not seem to appear on other questions, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369573/relational-sets-for-reflexive-symmetric-anti-symmetric-and-transitive?rq=1).
- This error, I imagine, does not depend on browser extensions (I don't even use Edge).
- I bugged my girlfriend about it, and it does appear for her on Chrome (the variant affecting $(4,4)$ only), and appear for her on Edge, in the variant below. She uses Windows 10 as well for what it's worth. (Lines added by me because this variant was new.)

[image]

---

It's a minor error since, as far as I know, it's purely visual and hard to notice unless pointed out or if you're used to seeing such errors. Still, I figured it worth bringing up -- any idea what could be causing this?